# Javascript regex in attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to use data attribute for regex just as

```
<div data-regex="REGEX-HERE">
```

and then get the value by javascript and put in a variable. and then do a test like

```
var regex = $(this).attr("data-regex");

regex.test(name)
```

when I tried to use "^[\x20-\x7E]+$"  for testing english character is didn't work.
Note when I tried this

```
var regex = /^[\x20-\x7E]+$/;
```

It worked.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So this ultimately has nothing to do with attributes, but rather creating a regular expression from a string, right? If so, search for that and you'll find lots of answers.

Comment: I didn't find. and I think here is simple for beginners (like me) to understand rather than a question with a big piece of code

Comment: That question is clearly summarized in the title, and the answer shows a  single line of code. That link is found as the first google result when searching *"javascript create regex from string"*. Don't know how it can get any easier. It has nothing to do with being a beginner. Being a beginner doesn't excuse you from basic research efforts.

Comment: Yes sure, my excuse that English isn't my mother tongue and I can't speak / write it probably. I don't know what mean string. I have seen the code in the question you mentioned to, but I didn't understand what is going on. It may be easy for you to understand but for me it is hard.

Comment: Many people here don't have English as a native language. And even so, the term "string" doesn't help a perfect English speaker either. That is JavaScript language terminology. If you don't know that term, then you've not bothered to learn the basics, which would be another problem. Hard to believe that you know "regex" and "variable" but not "string".

Comment: And if you believe or not, I am without learning PHP basics I have created this http://codecanyon.net/item/ppdf-document-hosting-script/7518665 What I need is just idea and then I will start building after searching on the web, already created codes :D

Comment: No idea what PHP has to do with this. What you need to do is learn the language before using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var regex = new RegExp("^[\x20-\x7E]+$",""); // Modifiers on the tend
```

So finally:

```
var regex = new RegExp($(this).data("regex"));

regex.test(name)
```

Comment: dat w3schools citation tho...

Comment: I am aware of the W3 is uncool protocol. But it has an explaination.

Comment: `new RegExp($(this).data('regex'))` is a little nicer

Comment: Agree since data attributes are automaticaly tranferred to the data object once called one time.